# how can i resolve the director issue in corona

Tags: ios, coronasdk

```
local function connectedToServer(event)


    client:send("connected")
    cleanAll()

    function a()
        director:changeScene( "PlayerClient" )
    end
    timer.performWithDelay( 1000, a() ,1) 




end
Runtime:addEventListener("autolanConnected", connectedToServer)
```

that is my line of code where there is an issue on changing the scene `director:changeScene( "PlayerClient" )`
 at 1st it ran fine but on the 2nd run when i paused the game or after I win or loss i go back to the menu and then I start the game again, there is an error in that line `director:changeScene( "PlayerClient" )`. Can anybody help me?

Error is

```
2013-01-09 14:51:25.871 Corona Simulator[478:707] Runtime error
    ...arooqi/Desktop/Crazy Candy 5 Jan 2013 5/director.lua:1060: attempt to call method 'insert' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'insert'
    ...arooqi/Desktop/Crazy Candy 5 Jan 2013 5/director.lua:1060: in function 'changeScene'
    ...arooqi/Desktop/Crazy Candy 5 Jan 2013 5/wifigame.lua:276: in function 'a'
    ...arooqi/Desktop/Crazy Candy 5 Jan 2013 5/wifigame.lua:278: in function <...arooqi/Desktop/Crazy Candy 5 Jan 2013 5/wifigame.lua:269>
    ?: in function 'dispatchEvent'
    .../Farooqi/Desktop/Crazy Candy 5 Jan 2013 5/Client.lua:373: in function '_listener'
    ?: in function <?:534>
    ?: in function <?:229>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
timer.performWithDelay(1000,function () direcor:changeScene( "PlayerClient" ) end)
```

instead of:

```
function a()
   direcor:changeScene( "PlayerClient" )
end

timer.performWithDelay(1000,a(),1)
```

Comment: then the problame is in ur siurce. can you show me all source code by wifigae.lua ?